# Remove <p> tags from product attributes in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

WooCommerce automatically adds a `<p>` tag to all product attributes after the weight and dimensions. This means that the formating of the product attributes changes after the first 2 lines.

I believe the code below (pulled from wc-template-functions.php) is where the `<p>` is automatically added, however I cannot figure out how to remove the `wpautop` without editing wc-template-functions.php directly. I am sure this can be applied with some sort of a filter. Any help figuring out how to remove this would be greatly appreciated.

```
$product_attributes[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title_with_dashes( $attribute->get_name() ) ] = array(
            'label' => wc_attribute_label( $attribute->get_name() ),
            'value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values ),
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the available filter hook `woocommerce_attribute` removing `wpautop()` like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute', 'woocommerce_attribute_filter_callback', 10, 3 );
function woocommerce_attribute_filter_callback( $formatted_values, $attribute, $values ) {
    return wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
str_ireplace(array('<p>','</p>'),'',wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ) )
```